# rvm list known に ruby-2.3.0がいない

Tags: ruby, rvm

### rvmでRubyのバージョンを2.3.0へ上げる準備

**.ruby-version**

```
2.3.0
```

としたところ

#### ターミナルにメッセージが現れる

ターミナルに

```
ruby-2.3.0-preview1 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.3.0-preview1'
```

と出たので

### rvm list knownにいない

`% rvm list known`

してみましたが、一覧に`ruby-2.3.0`を見受けられませんでした。

### rvm をバージョンアップしてみた（バージョンアップという表現で正しいのかどうか？）

そこで
[ruby - Update RVM list known - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650164/update-rvm-list-known)
を参考に

`% rvm get stable`

した後

ターミナルに出るメッセージから`preview1`が消え

```
ruby-2.3.0 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.3.0'
```

になりました。

### やはり rvm list knownにいない

このとき、やはり一覧にありません。

```
% rvm list known             
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-head] # security released on head
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p330]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p551]
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p643]
[ruby-]2.1.4
[ruby-]2.1[.5]
[ruby-]2.2[.1]
[ruby-]2.2-head
ruby-head

# for forks use: rvm install ruby-head-<name> --url https://github.com/github/ruby.git --branch 2.1

# JRuby
jruby-1.6.8
jruby[-1.7.19]
jruby-head
jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1

# Rubinius
rbx-1.4.3
rbx-2.4.1
rbx[-2.5.2]
rbx-head

# Opal
opal

# Minimalistic ruby implementation - ISO 30170:2012
mruby[-head]

# Ruby Enterprise Edition
ree-1.8.6
ree[-1.8.7][-2012.02]

# GoRuby
goruby

# Topaz
topaz

# MagLev
maglev[-head]
maglev-1.0.0

# Mac OS X Snow Leopard Or Newer
macruby-0.10
macruby-0.11
macruby[-0.12]
macruby-nightly
macruby-head

# IronRuby
ironruby[-1.1.3]
ironruby-head
```

### 仕方がないのでターミナルの出力通りインストールしてみる

`% rvm install ruby-2.3.0`
したところ無事にインストールが完了しました。

### インストール完了したのにまだ一覧にいない

```
% rvm list known             
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-head] # security released on head
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p330]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p551]
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p643]
[ruby-]2.1.4
[ruby-]2.1[.5]
[ruby-]2.2[.1]
[ruby-]2.2-head
ruby-head

# for forks use: rvm install ruby-head-<name> --url https://github.com/github/ruby.git --branch 2.1

# JRuby
jruby-1.6.8
jruby[-1.7.19]
jruby-head
jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1

# Rubinius
rbx-1.4.3
rbx-2.4.1
rbx[-2.5.2]
rbx-head

# Opal
opal

# Minimalistic ruby implementation - ISO 30170:2012
mruby[-head]

# Ruby Enterprise Edition
ree-1.8.6
ree[-1.8.7][-2012.02]

# GoRuby
goruby

# Topaz
topaz

# MagLev
maglev[-head]
maglev-1.0.0

# Mac OS X Snow Leopard Or Newer
macruby-0.10
macruby-0.11
macruby[-0.12]
macruby-nightly
macruby-head

# IronRuby
ironruby[-1.1.3]
ironruby-head
```

どうして一覧に出ないんでしょうか？

### rvmのバージョン

rvm 1.26.11 (latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.26.11にはまだ2.3.0が含まれていないようですね。

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/1.26.11/config/known#L11

最新のmasterには含まれているので次のバージョンアップで表示されるかもです。

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/config/known#L10

https://rvm.io/rubies/list を見ると、

> NOTE: Even though this is all *known* rubies, RVM can install many more rubies not listed :)

とあるので、knownに表示されるかどうかはインストールできるかどうかと無関係みたいです。

Comment: 静的ファイルを表示してるだけだったんですね！？